# I am trying to validate phone number

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to validate phone number using regex, and I want to create a phone number format like this:

> (+971 12 123 1234)

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: i have this type of validation code

Comment: $phone_regex = "^[0-9]{3,4}[\s]{1}[0-9]{3}[-]{1}[0-9]{4}$";
     $inputmask = "999 999-9999";

Comment: And i want to change this +971 12 123 1234 formate

Comment: If you're going to use this for an end-user facing application, I believe that forcing people to write a phone number in a specific format is a bad idea;  as long as they give you a valid phone number, then the positioning of the spaces should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
var phone_regex = /^\(\d{3]\ \d{2]\ \d{3]\ \d{4]\)$/;
```

More Detail to refer

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/04/30/10-examples-of-basic-input-validation-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$
```

This will a Help for you.